# Enum error in FreeMarker template

Tags: java, enums, freemarker

I have the following

```
public enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}
```

and

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Gender gender;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

In a FreeMarker termplate `${person.name}` works fine, but `${person.gender}` gives `Expression person.gender is undefined on ...`.

Any idea why?

Comment: can you show the complete error..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when the method `getGender` was returning null. Although the error message is not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

user `person.gender.MALE` or `person.gender.FEMALE`

Comment: It gives the same error. Actually it doesn't even make sense.